# find out the average height in python by nationality using numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a dataset like this (array)

| weight | height | gender | blood | nationality |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 175 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 40 | 176 | 2 | 2 | 1 |

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.loadtxt("data/details.csv",delimeter=",")

weight =arr(:,0)
height =arr(:,1)
gender =arr(:,2)
blood =arr(:,3)
nationality =arr(:,4)
```

Now I would like to find out which nationality (there are 5) has the highest average height

I gave that code

```
height.mean(nationality)
```

But I got an error message

By the way these dataset has 5000 entries

Comment: Hi! Adding the output of the error message and what steps you've taken to try to solve the problem increase the likelihood of finding an answer.

Comment: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: Please see [ask] and the [help]. Always provide a [mcve]. The code you provided *doesn't even compile*. Furthermore, it relies on some external dataset that we don't have access to. If you are getting an error message, post the *full error message including the stack trace in the question itself*. The python runtime goes through great lengths to give you those error messages with a bunch of useful information, why would you just omit that?

Answer (score 1):

Refer to the numpy documentation for [numpy.ndarray.mean()](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.mean.html). You are passing an array that does not correspond to the positional arguments for `.mean()` (i.e. axis).

I would recommend using Pandas for a job like this, as its builtin functions make conditional statistics easier. You can import your file with

```
import pandas as pd
arr = pd.read_csv("data/details.csv", sep=",")
```

Then, use the groupby method to divide your data by nationality:

```
df = arr.groupby('nationality')
```

This new DataFrame will organize the data by classes (e.g. 1, 3, etc.) of `nationality` and you can use `.mean()` to get the mean values for each variable:

```
df.mean()

nationality weight  height  gender  blood               
1            40     176     2       2
3            50     175     1       3
```